# yum-builddep fails to retrieve an unrelated RPM and fails - how to prevent?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I'm trying to download sources required to build `nekovm` using `yum-builddep`, accidentally, I have `nodejs` RPM in the list, which is irrelevant to Neko, but it causes `yum-builddep` to fail, when searching for repositories. Here's how the output looks like:

```
$ sudo yum-builddep nekovm
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
http://nodejs.tchol.org/stable/f17/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Couldn't connect"
Trying other mirror.
Enabling fedora-source repository
Enabling nodejs-stable-source repository
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://nodejs.tchol.org/mirrors/nodejs-stable-source-f17 error was
14: curl#7 - "Couldn't connect"
Could not setup repo nodejs-stable-source: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: nodejs-stable-source/17
```

Nodejs repository is just bad, it's there, but it often times down, so I don't want to remove it entirely, just ignore it, if it fails. Is there any way to address this?

Comment: The output says that the command is not connecting to the source repositories. I don't think it has a chance of working if it can't connect to the repositories.

Comment: @ZaSter it only fails to connect to a repository it doesn't need anyway. But nevermind, I just edited the `/etc/yum.repos.d/nodejs-stable.repo` to disable it for the time being and I could download the dependencies I needed. Still, out of curiosity, would like to know it it would be possible to just skip the missing repos instead of failing.

Comment: Take a look at the output from running `yum-builddep --help`. The yum base options --tolerant and --skip-broken might help to bypass the failures. Also using the --disablerepo option eliminate the need to edit the repo file itself.

Comment: @ZaSter ha!.. this is what you get if you read man pages instead. You can make you last comment an answer. That precisely answers the question! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the man pages for some commands, like this one, do not even hint that there is a `--help` that can be invoked to learn more about the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the output from running `yum-builddep --help`. The yum base options `--tolerant` and `--skip-broken` might help to bypass the failures. Also using the `--disablerepo` option eliminates the need to edit the repo file itself.